# Access Visual Studio's $exception variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I have a situation where an `onClose` event Handler is running due to an exception thrown.

If I force it to happen with the VS debugger attached, then I can see in VS 'Locals' a `$exception` local variable, which has (somewhat) interesting information on it.

But I can't figure out how to get at that exception within the code, so that I can log it. :(

- The eventArgs of my eventHandler are just the `Empty` Event.
- Asking `Marshall.GetExceptionCode/Pointers()` doesn't give me anything useful.

Evidently something knows about this exception, because VS can show it to me ... how can I get at that exception?

Comment: What is this for type of app? And on what instance does that OnClose event run?

Comment: What do you mean by *"`onClose` event handler is running due to an exception thrown"*? How is an exception causing `onClose` to run?

Comment: Visual Studio is able to show it to you because it's the process's debugger. It caught the exception first and read it from the evaluation stack before letting the `catch` block run (which takes it from the evaluation stack). By the time execution reaches your code, it's a local variable higher in the call stack. Because the call stack is an implementation detail and slot allocation is subject to JIT decisions, walking the call stack to look for a local variable is unreliable at best.

Comment: Following from @madreflection. VS magically grabs the current exception and puts it in the `$exception` pseudo variable in order to make your debugging experience better.  The only place you have access (in your code) to it in in a `catch` block.  If you want to capture it, you need to do it there. There are a bunch more pseudo-variables the VS debugger makes available to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that might be the answer. Ah well ...

Comment: @Flydog57 do you want to post that as an answer. (Roughly as I understand it: VS can do it becaus it's managing the whole process, so it can keep track of things that we *previously* in scope but are no long in scope. So it's definitely not possible by normal, intended means. It *might* be possible to find it by reflecting up the CallStack but it's definitely not a normal thing to be able to do.)

Comment: Even though it won't help me solve my original problem, "No that thing is definitively not possible" is a very helpful answer to have for future developers.

Comment: Just ask the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown, regardless whether it is handled.  In VS2017+ use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings, tick the checkbox for CLR exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The capability you really want doesn't exist.  VS magically grabs the current exception and puts it in the `$exception` pseudo variable in order to make your debugging experience better.

The only place you have access (in your code) to it in in a `catch` block. If you want to capture it, you need to do it there. There are a bunch more pseudo-variables the VS debugger makes available to you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables?view=vs-2019